# Remember me functionality using cookies is not working php

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to implement cookies for remember me functionality using php.But, I don't think that with my code, the cookies are getting enabled.

```
<?php require_once 'config.php'
    ?> 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
        </head>

    <body>

       <form class="Login" method="post" action="private.php">

           <div type="submit" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 login">Login</div>
           <div type="submit" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 sign_up">Sign up</div>


             <input type="text" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 username" id="username_login" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" name="member_name" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_login"]; } ?>" />

         <input type="password" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 password" id="password_login" placeholder="Password" name="member_password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_password"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_password"]; } ?>"/>      
            <div class="row remember col-md-11 col-xs-11">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> checked <?php } ?>/> Remember Me </label>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-md-11 col-xs-11">
              <button type="submit" id="button" name="login">Login</button>
            </div>
               </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

The configuration file in which I am setting the values of cookies is like this:

```
<?php require 'database.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

session_start();
if(!empty($_POST["login"])) {
    #$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog_samples");
    $sql = "Select * from login where Username = '" . $_POST["member_name"] . "' and Password = '" . ($_POST["member_password"]) . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($user) {
    if($_POST["remember"]==1) {
        setcookie ("member_login",$_POST["member_name"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        setcookie ("member_password",$_POST["member_password"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        setcookie($_POST["remember"],1);
        header("location:private.php");
    }

}
}
?>
```

And the end page, i.e. private.php is like this

```
<?php
echo"Hello";
session_start();
#$_SESSION["member_id"] = "";
session_destroy();
#header("Location:private.php");
?>
```

When I refresh my browser, after logging in using username and password with remember me checked,then the input fields are not pre-populated with the same username and password.I think the cookies are not getting set.What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: A few tips not related to your actual problem: You have a wide SQL injection vulnerability there so everybody can easily hack your app and log in (google it). Also, you shouldn't store passwords in cleartext, and by far you shouldn't store them also in a cookie _and_ prefill them in a login box (that's the job of the browser's password manager, not yours)... A remember me function should store the information that the user was logged in (with part of the data stored server-side-only, e.g. with a session) and skip the login in that case.

Comment: yeah, in my actual code,I have done the encryption @CherryDT

Comment: First, CherryDT is correct in all of his points.  But, I do understand some quick hacking just to help put ideas into a working form.  In your situation, I'd add some debugging to your code to help.  Not sure if the cookies are being set, then add a little code:  <!-- <?php print_r($_COOKIE); ?> --> to print out the cookie data to know for sure.  I added html comments around it, so its only viewable if you view source, which may be overkill for your needs.  Once you know if the cookie data is actually set, you can narrow down the problem from there...

Comment: The cookies are not getting added.That is the issue.I have debugged it using inspect element in the browser. No cookie is gettng created and I don't know why it is happening @R.Smith

Comment: Is your code making it into the if structure where the cookies are created?  I'd verify that as well.  Baby steps, is how we do it :)

Comment: i don't know.how do i check that? I am very new to php